# Postgres DB USER Creation

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgres and want to know if there is a way to CREATE a DB USER in such a way that it will have access to ALL the SCHEMA's including those which are not created yet, I mean access to all the current and future schema's.I have multiple Schema's in my Postgres DB which have the same Tables.If the above is possible I want this user to have SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE on only 2 Tables in the existing and future created Schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` to give a user permissions on future schemas and tables, but you cannot restrict that to certain table names.

You may be able to do that with an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/event-triggers.html).

Personally, I would put `GRANT` statements into the code that creates the tables.